# One sample T-test in python not giving the desired output

Tags: python, hypothesis-test

I have a dataframe called `df_salaire` that has age, marital status,...., number of working hours per week,...

I want to test if the number of working hours per week is around 40h per week, I used to `dataframe.mean()` and the output was 40.37

However, when I t test using `ttest_1samp` like this:

```
ttest, pval = ttest_1samp(np.array(df_salaire['heures.par.semaine']), 40)
print(pval)
```

I get a pvalue that is less than 0.05, so the number of working hours is not around 40h per week.

Which is contradictory.

Am I missing something?

Comment: I don't think it is contradictory. Suppose you have a dataset with ten elements: [40.4, 40.4, 40.4, 40.4, 40.4, 40.4, 40.4, 40.3, 40.3, 40.3]. In this case, you have a sample mean of 40.37, but a T-test reports that it is very unlikely that you would get this data if the true mean is 40. So by one metric, 40.37 is close to 40, but by another metric, it is very different.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is one of statistics, not of coding. "Around" 40 hours is a very fuzzy concept. If you're dealing with the amount of time someone works, 40.37 is "around" 40 hours. If you're dealing with computer uptime in microseconds, then 40.37 may not be close enough to 40.00000 hours to be acceptable.

So what you need to do is specify what your acceptable range is. If you are willing to accept anything that is +/- 0.5 hours, then you have two tests that you need to make:

1. Is the average statistically greater than 39.5 hours?
2. Is the average statistically less than 40.5 hours?

If both of those tests pass, then you know that your average is statistically within 0.5 hours of 40.

Both of those statistical questions can be "phrased" as 1-tailed t-tests, though you may need to do some reading to figure out how to properly "phrase the question".

Comment: If the issue is statistics, then it is not a programming problem, and it is not appropriate to ask/answer in Stack Overflow.